# How can I calculate a critical t value using R?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

Sorry if this is a newb question; I'm trying to teach myself statistics for the first time.  I think I have the basic procedure down, but I'm struggling to execute it with R.

So, I'm trying to evaluate the significance of regression coefficients in a multiple linear regression of form

$$ \hat y = X \hat \beta$$

I think the t-statistic for testing $H_0: \hat \beta_j = 0, H_a: \hat \beta_j \neq 0$ is given by

$$t_0 = \frac{\hat \beta_j - 0}{\text{se}(\hat \beta_j)} = \frac{\hat \beta_j}{\sqrt{\hat \sigma^2 C_{jj}}} = \frac{\hat \beta_j}{\sqrt{C_{jj} SS_{Res}/(n-p)}}$$
where $C_{jj}$ is the $j^{th}$ diagonal entry in $(X'X)^{-1}$.

So far, so good. I know how to calculate all of these values using matrix operations in R.  But in order to reject the null, the book says I need
$$|t_0| > t_{\alpha/2,n-p}$$

**How can I compute this critical value $t_{\alpha/2,n-p}$ using R?**  Right now the only way I know how to find these values is by looking in the table in the back of the book.  There must be a better way.

Comment: The qt() function does this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Welcome to the Stats Stackexchange. You can compute the $t_{\alpha/2, n-p}$ critical value in R by doing `qt(1-alpha/2, n-p)`.

In the following example, I ask R to give me the $95\%$ critical value for $df=1, 2, \dots, 10$. The result is a list of the first ten critical values for the t-distribution at the given confidence level:
`> qt(.975, 1:10)

 [1] 12.706205  4.302653  3.182446  2.776445  2.570582  2.446912  2.364624  2.306004  2.262157  2.228139`